# Compiler returning invalid syntax error when using time.ctime()

Tags: python, time, module

So today I was writing a relatively childish program in Python for opening a recreational video on YouTube after  a certain period of time. More like a break time thing so that it opened a random pick from a list of URLs. Here's the code :

```
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
from time import *
import random

print("Hello! This program was started at " time.ctime())

totalBreaks = 5000
breaksTaken = 0

url = ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXWrjWDQh7Q', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?    v=yNLdblFQqsw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tD4HCZe-tew',         'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GTyN-DB_v5M', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n49qi-dU9IE', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2iFa5We6zqw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEI4qSrkPAs', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzTuBuRdAyA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kqQDCxRCzM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u2cphuMbqfc']

while (breaksTaken > totalBreaks) :
time.sleep(60)
webbroswer.open(choice.random(url))
```

Comment: Your print misses a comma and your `while` block is not indented.

Comment: Python Compiler, lolwut.

Comment: @PeterNimroot What about it?

Comment: Python has no such thing that could be called a compiler, unless we're talking about PyPy's JIT compiler. Converting code to byte-code (*.pyc) can't be called compiling, because byte-code can't be ran by CPU without PVM.

Comment: @PeterNimroot What's about Nuitka?

Comment: @PeterNimroot If it can't be called compiling, then how come [the official documentation does exactly that](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-bytecode)?

Comment: Nuitka is not part of official Python implementation. About the official docs - it seems like the author of that part had rather loose approach to the process of compiling. With such understanding I could define representing `'ó'` => `'\xc3\xb3'` as a process of compilation as well.

Comment: @PeterNimroot It's not just that part, you can find it elsewhere as well, for example in the `dis` module, linked to by that glossary entry. And it's not even just the documentation - explain the existence/name of [compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile), one of the few built-in functions. And feel free to show places calling `'ó'` => `'\xc3\xb3'` compilation, preferably in the Python documentation.

Comment: @PeterNimroot Btw, please include `@name` so people get notified. Or is that a poor attempt at getting the last word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import os
import sys
import webbrowser
import time

# Added explanation #0:
# Always try to avoid import *
# and if still you do 'from time import sleep' or 'from time import *'
# then there will be different namespace, so you'd use: sleep(1)
# but not time.sleep(1) -- and this is not Pythonic way.

import random

print("Hello! This program was started at %s " % time.ctime())

# Added explanation #1:
# You should concatenate output in print ^^^^^^^^^^ statement

totalBreaks = 5000
breaksTaken = 0

url = ['http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OXWrjWDQh7Q',
       'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yNLdblFQqsw',
       'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tD4HCZe-tew']

while (breaksTaken > totalBreaks):
    time.sleep(60)
    webbroswer.open(random.choice(url))
# Added explanation #2:
# You should use random.choice(), not a choice.random()

# That's all, folks!
```

Comment: What is different? Could you please add some context?

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: @FrankerZ FFFFixed!

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much for heloing out @pmus!